# Using DQL functions inside Doctrine 2 ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by

I'm doing a project in Symfony 2.3 with Doctrine 2.4 using MySQL database.

I have an Entity of FieldValue (simplified):

```
class FieldValue
{
    /**
     * The ID
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $fieldValueId;

    /**
     * Id of associated Field entity
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $fieldId;

    /**
     * Id of associated user
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $userId;

    /**
     * The value for the Field that user provided
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $userValue;

    /**
     * @var \MyProjectBundle\Entity\Field
     */
    protected $field;

    /**
     * @var \MyProjectBundle\Entity\User
     */
    protected $user;
```

The problem I have is the fact that `$userValue`, while it's `LONGTEXT` in my database, can represent either actual text value , date  or number, depending in the type of the `Field`.

The Field can be dynamically added. After adding a one to any of the users every other user can also fill it's own value for that Field.

While querying the database I use orderBy to sort on a certain column, which also can be one of those Fields. In that case I need to sort on `$userValue`. This is problematic when I need to have number fields sorted as numbers, and not as strings ('123' is less than '9' in that case...).

The solution for it (I thought) is to `CAST` the `$sort`, so I would get SQL like:

```
ORDER BY CAST(age AS SIGNED INTEGER) ASC
```

Since Doctrine does not have a built-in DQL function for that, I took the liberty of adding that to my project as `INT` DQL  function (thanks to [Jasper N. Brouwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405342/casting-attributes-for-ordering-on-a-doctrine2-dql-query)):

```
class CastAsInteger extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringPrimary;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'CAST(' . $this->stringPrimary->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ' AS SIGNED INTEGER)';
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->stringPrimary = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

So happy with myself finding an easy solution I did that:

```
$sort = "INT(".$sort.")";

$queryBuilder->orderBy($sort, $dir);
```

which produced expected DQL:

```
ORDER BY INT(age) ASC
```

But also produced an exception:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 12272: Error: Expected end of string, got '('") in MyProject...**

So I've tried to find out what is going on and got into this in `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php`:

```
/**
     * OrderByItem ::= (
     *      SimpleArithmeticExpression | SingleValuedPathExpression |
     *      ScalarExpression | ResultVariable
     * ) ["ASC" | "DESC"]
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\OrderByItem
     */
    public function OrderByItem()
    {
        ...
    }
```

Does that mean that there is no possibility to use DQL functions inside `ORDER BY`?
And if this is the case - is there any other way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I actually already have INT used in my select query, inside `CASE WHEN`:

```
if ($field->getFieldType() == 'number') {
    $valueThen = "INT(".$valueThen.")";
}

$newFieldAlias = array("
    (CASE
        WHEN ...
        THEN ".$valueThen."
        ELSE ...
        END
    ) as ".$field->getFieldKey());
```

Later on the `$newFieldAlias` is being added to the query.

Doesn't change anything...

**UPDATE 2**

Even when I add an extra select to the query, which will result in this DQL:

```
SELECT age, INT(age) as int_age
```

and then sort like that:

```
ORDER BY int_age ASC
```

I still don't het the correct result.

I've checked `var_dump` from `$query->getResult()`, and this is what I got:

```
'age' => string '57' (length=2)      
'int_age' => string '57' (length=2)
```

Like CAST does not matter. I'm clueless...

Comment: I think the way I got around this was to alias the field and then order by the alias.  So you could try 'INT(".$sort.") as SortBy' in the select fields part and then order on that alias.

Comment: Yea sorry all my doctrine stuff is at work so I cant check it, but I do remember having a similar issue.

Answer (score 6):

Doctrine DQL does not accept functions as sort criteria but it does accept a "result variable". It means that you can do the following:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->addSelect('INT(age) as HIDDEN int_age')
    ->orderBy('int_age');
```

Comment: The fact that you still get results as string instead of integers isn't related to the original issue. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo)

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine 2 does not support INT by default, but you can use age+0.

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->addSelect('age+0 as HIDDEN int_age')
    ->orderBy('int_age');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is problem in your parser.php file. I have similar kind of issue and I solve this issue to replace below code in my parser file.

```
/**
     * OrderByClause ::= "ORDER" "BY" OrderByItem {"," OrderByItem}*
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\OrderByClause
     */
    public function OrderByClause()
    {
        $this->match(Lexer::T_ORDER);
        $this->match(Lexer::T_BY);

        $orderByItems = array();
        $orderByItems[] = $this->OrderByItem();

        while ($this->lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_COMMA)) {
            $this->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

            $orderByItems[] = $this->OrderByItem();
        }

        return new AST\OrderByClause($orderByItems);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this:

```
->orderBy('u.age + 0', 'ASC');
```