# In Symfony where do I register a custom DQL function?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405342/casting-attributes-for-ordering-on-a-doctrine2-dql-query) how to do a custom DQL function. But in what file do I put the register function part ? I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: Not mentioned in the doc ?? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Comment: You're right. Edited the question. I couldn't find it, because initally I was looking in doctrine's documentation, not symfony's. If you check the editions on this question you'll see that initially I asked about doctrine. Thanks.

Comment: You should update your answer and accept it for futur visitors.

Comment: I made this question today. I only alllows this after 2 days. But about answer update, what should I update ? didn't  get that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it.

You can register it on config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                INT: YourProject\YourBundle\Folder\CastAsInteger
```