# how to cast COUNT return type in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I'd like to know if there's a way to convert/cast the count type that doctrine returns,

When I do

```
$queryBuilder->select('p.idPublication,
    p.publicationName as name,
    p.publicationDescription as description,
    p.publicationPhoto as photoPublication')
 ->addSelect('(SELECT COUNT(com.idCommentaire)FROM PublicationBundle:Commentaire com
    WHERE com.publication = p.idPublication) as comments')
```

...

I get the comments  as string. how can I convert the `COUNT` result to int.

Thank you all.

Comment: Maybe you can create your own function like in this question : [Casting attributes for Ordering on a Doctrine2 DQL Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405342/casting-attributes-for-ordering-on-a-doctrine2-dql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you store the results of that query in a `$results` variable, then you can cast it to an `int` like this:

```
$intVal = (int) $results[$rowNumber]['comments']
```

If you wanted to perform the cast in the query then you could add `+ 0` to your select statement. Like this:

```
'SELECT (COUNT(com.idCommentaire) + 0) FROM ...'
```

However, casting within the query will also require you to use `getScalarResult()` as Doctrine returns results as a string by default.

Comment: I just tried it it doesn't work, still return string type

Comment: when i var_dump the result i get `'comments' => string '3' (length=1)`

Comment: I think that Doctrine returns results as a string unless you use `getScalarResult()` but I don't think you can use that with your current query because your query also returns string values. Is there a reason you NEED to cast the count to an integer?

Comment: If there is a need i'll do it in php when I get the result, I was just wondering if there's a way to do something like `CAST(COUNT(...) AS INTEGER` ?